# how to set IIS Express applicationhost to local drive

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express, iis-8

My organization's network policy has set %userprofile% and moved all contents in My Documents to a network folder. Whenever I need to open solution containing both web projects and library projects in Visual Studio 2017, I have to connect to the network.  Otherwise, the VS always says that I don't have permission to access IIS configuration file, thus it would not allow me to open the web project. The library project opens fine though. How can I work on projects offline without changing %IIS_USER_HOME%, %IIS_SITES_HOME%, %IIS_BIN%, or $USERPROFILE%?  Thanx.

Comment: Web projects in VS 2017 do not use the configuration file in `My Documents` https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html#add-iis-express-from-visual-studio-2015-2017-solution-file So it is not clear to me what exactly is the error you met.

Comment: The %IIS_USER_HOME% is by default mapped to "%USERPORFILE% which by default is mapped to "c:\users\myName\My Documents".